# How to pass data from superclass to subclass?

Tags: ios, swift

I send data from FirstViewController using segue, I receive it in ViewController where I want to access a variable located in a superclass from a subclass..
here's my code for now

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {


public var count: String = ""

}

class Counter  {

func loadData(){

print(count)
}
}
```

Results either empty or nil
Thank you

Comment: Have a look at https://www.hackingwithswift.com/example-code/uikit/what-is-a-segue

Comment: What is the superclass and what is the subclass in this question?

Comment: This code doesn't even compile. There is no superclass/subclass relationship shown.

Answer (score 0):

The `Counter` class has no relationship to the `ViewController` class in terms of inheritance. This is not a superclass/subclass relationship.

Defining the class inside the `ViewController` class doesn't give it any access to `ViewController` instance properties

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to pass some data to an instance of a class is a property. Assuming we have

```
class Counter {
    public var count: String
    // ...
    // initialization etc.
    // ...    
    func loadData() {
        print(count)
    }
}
```

Now we can pass our data

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    public var count: String = ""

    var myCounter: Counter

    // instantiate myCounter in some way
    myCounter.count = count
}
```